# why google app script 'copyTo' range method filling with 0?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

consider the following code:

```
/**********************************************************************************************
 **  FUNCTION : CarryToThisWeek                                                              **
 **  PARAM    : String lastWeekName, String thisWeekName                                     **
 **  RETUEN   : VOID                                                                         **
 **  DESC     : Copies the carry row of sheet named lastWeekName to B/F row of sheet named   **
 **             thisWeekName.                                                                **
 **********************************************************************************************/

function CarryToThisWeek(lastWeekName,thisWeekName){
  var spreadSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastSheet=spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Oct_06'); // hard-coded the names for testing
  var thisSheet=spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Oct_13');
  var sourceData = lastSheet.getRange(38, 4, 1, 7);
  Logger.log(sourceData.getValues()); //shows the correct values
  var destination = thisSheet.getRange(33, 4, 1, 7);
  sourceData.copyTo(destination); //fills with 0 <<<<<
  //following loop works fine
  /*for(col=4;col<=10;col++){
    thisSheet.getRange(33, col).setValue(lastSheet.getRange(38, col).getValue());
  }*/
}
```

I am fairly new to google app scripts, though I have used the `copyTo` method successfully in some other place previously.

I fear I am missing something very silly.

Can someone please point me to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: With all respect there are times I miss this - Is the sourceData formula field.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function CarryToThisWeek(lastWeekName,thisWeekName){
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Oct_06'); 
  var thisSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Oct_13');
  var sourceData = lastSheet.getRange(38, 4, 1, 7).getValues();
  thisSheet.getRange(33, 4, 1, 7).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this will work. But actually I wanted to know what is wrong in `copyTo` method in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this.

Thanks [Vasim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2519002/vasim) for the point.
Indeed `sourceData` **is a formula field and the formula was being copied all the time**.

Changed that to

```
sourceData.copyTo(destination,{contentsOnly:true});
```

and it is working as expected.

I think `copyValuesToRange()` will also work.